# How to make downloader URL HTTPS -- can't pass PCI scan

Tags: downloader, pci

We are doing our scheduled PCI scan and for some odd reason, this year they aren't letting the magentostore.com/downloader url slide. It's being marked as an automatic failure due to the plain text form.

They are saying this URL should be HTTPS.

I looked at some of the biggest sites using MagentoCE and Eneterprise, and they too use an HTTP url for the Magento Connect /downloader/ url.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Samuel

Comment: If you don't use magento connect just delete the download folder.

Comment: Seriously? That's it? We don't use it at all. This won't hurt how we manually import files through cpanel or ftp? I see some theme functions got imported into the plugins section of Magento connect. Though we uploaded theme via cpanel.

Comment: You use FTP!?! Hopefully with encryption, if not, change it. And yes, that's all. If the directory doesn't exist, apache does its normal 404 :-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt please post it as an answer so that it can be accepted and we have one more answered question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use magento connect just delete the download folder.